# What algorithm is used to produce the 32 bit password key in an edit protected microsoft office (specifically word) document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, passwords, password-protection, hashing

If you save a legacy (.doc era) word document with edit protection, you can find the password key stored within the file.

For ease, this can be found by saving to an .xml or .html file and inspecting the text source (but you can also pull it out from the original .doc with a hex editor).  For example, with the password "password", you'll find the following in the source:

`<w:documentProtection w:edit="forms" w:enforcement="on" w:unprotectPassword="147A83AF"/>`

What algorithm is used to produce this key, which appears to be a 32 bit hexadecimal?

Comment: [What algorithm does Microsoft Office 2010 use for encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501894/what-algorithm-does-microsoft-office-2010-use-for-encryption)

Comment: that is not a hash created by a modern algorithm. it is way  to short. see here for examples of many common hashes: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes

Comment: @Seth That question is about document encryption in the new office format, I'm asking about password protection on unencrypted files in the legacy office format

Comment: It goes back to Pre-Windows 2007. If that isn't old enough you will have to be more specific.

Comment: @seth I'm talking about the key included in the .doc format i.e. the native format of word 2003 and earlier (still available in all modern versions of office, along with other associated legacy formats) and, just to be double clear, this is not about encrypted files, but edit protected.

Comment: This thread may be informative: https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-3665-page-3.html "Once you know the RC4 key, you have the first five bytes of the MD5|SHA1 hash. You then collide that hash to find a password that works."

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that output with a current Office Installation. At least that value should stand for "password" according to [this](http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/13/t/345.aspx).

Taking these sources into account:

- [PenTestCorner - Cracking Microsoft Office (97-03, 2007, 2010, 2013) password hashes with Hashcat](http://pentestcorner.com/cracking-microsoft-office-97-03-2007-2010-2013-password-hashes-with-hashcat/)
- [InfoSecSee - Cracking Password Protected Word, Excel, and Powerpoint Documents](http://blog.infosecsee.com/2015/02/cracking-password-protected-word-excel.html)

It looks like those older versions are using a combination of Hashing and Encryption. It would appear you'd have to check a bit more about the file in order to figure out what kind of combination it's actually using.

InfoSecSee has a rather nice picture in regards to this:
[image: InfoSecSee Office Password Algorithm documentation]

This seems to match with the list from PenTestCorner:

- Office 97-03(MD5+RC4,oldoffice$0,oldoffice$1): flag -m 9700
- Office 97-03(MD5+RC4,collider-mode#1): flag -m 9710
- Office 97-03(MD5+RC4,collider-mode#2): flag -m 9720
- Office 97-03(SHA1+RC4,oldoffice$3,oldoffice$4): flag -m 9800
- Office 97-03(SHA1+RC4,collider-mode#1): flag -m 9810
- Office 97-03(SHA1+RC4,collider-mode#2): flag -m 9820
- Office 2007: flag -m 9400
- Office 2010: flag -m 9500
- Office 2013: flag -m 9600

You'd have to have check the specifics on how "Office2John" or hashcat is implemented to figure out further how to determine what algorithm is used etc.

Comment: The easiest way to reproduce it is to save a document into a legacy .xml format.  On the save as menu, select "word 2003 xml document" and then open it up in a text editor and ctrl f for "password".  You'll also find the same key in the binary but in reverse, bytewise (i.e if you inspect with a hex editor the key 12 34 56 78 would become 78 56 34 12 )